# My class doesn't work propery

Tags: c++, class, object, int

I'm getting an error in my code I don't get at all.

Here is my code:

**MyClass.h**

```
#include "MyClass.h"

int i = 1;

MyClass::MyClass()
{

}

MyClass:~MyClass()
{

}
```

**MyClass.cpp**
    #pragma once

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass();
        virtual ~MyClass();

        int i;
    protected:
    private:
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include "MyClass.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MyClass myObject = *new MyClass();

    cout << myObject.i << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

I just get some random number. Any help here?

Comment: You're leaking memory. Just create objects like this: `MyClass myObject;` -- Drop the call to `new`.

Comment: Your labels for `MyClass.h` and `MyClass.cpp` looks misplaced.

Comment: I appreciate code that compiles. Yours does not.

Comment: You need to learn C++, from a textbook, walkthroughs, etc.  At present you just threw stuff together until it compiled, now you're surprised it doesn't do one thing you were hoping it might.

Answer (score 2):

You are not initializing `i` in your class, your constructor should look something like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass() : i(1)
{}
```

It also looks like you have a few typos, this:

```
MyClass myObject = *new MyClass();
```

should be:

```
MyClass *myObject = new MyClass();
```

and this:

```
cout << myObject.i << endl;
```

should be:

```
cout << myObject->i << endl;
```

Although, as chris says the simpler option would be as follows:

```
MyClass myObject ;

cout << myObject.i << endl;
```

Comment: @chris Yeah, I know, I just like to keep as close as possible to OP's code. I amended my answer to suggest that as a simpler method.

Answer (score 0):

The i that you set to 1 is not a member of the class. It is a static variable outside of any class.

Answer (score 0):

Once i belongs to you class, you need to initialize it inside its constructor

```
#include "MyClass.h"

// int i = 1;   <-- not here

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    i = 1; // here
}
```

and to initialize your object in main function just do something like that:

```
int main()
{
//    MyClass myObject = *new MyClass();  <-- myObject is not a pointer
    MyClass myObject;

    cout << myObject.i << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: That's not initialization. That's assignment. It makes a difference when you try to call a constructor, or use a const or reference, or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things wrong:  First, you're redeclaring i in MyClass.cpp, try assigning to it in the constructor instead:

```
//int i = 1;

MyClass::MyClass() : i(1)
{

}
```

Second, the way you're declaring your object in your main() is wrong too.  Either you do:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass* myObject = new MyClass();

    cout << myObject->i << endl;
    cin.get();

    delete myObject;
}
```

if you want a pointer to a dynamically allocated object or just

```
int main()
{
    MyClass myObject;

    cout << myObject.i << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

if you want an object allocated on the stack.